# what does mxGetPr return?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

What is actually the value of mxGetPr(prhs[3])[i] in the following piece of code?

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
    {
       int *D = new int[100];
       // prhs[3] is a 10x10 matrix containing floating point value

       for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
           D[i] = mxGetPr(prhs[3])[i];
    }
```

Comment: What is `mxGetPr` and what does it return?

Comment: try `std::cout << mxGetPr(prhs[3])[i];`

Comment: It returns a `void*` type casted to a `double*`.  You need to check to make sure if its a double or a class using `mxIsDouble` or `mxIsClass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "matrix.h"
double *mxGetPr(const mxArray *pm);
```

> Pointer to the first element of the real data. Returns NULL in C (0 in Fortran) if there is no real data.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html